# Communication between fragment and activity (non-static method)

Tags: android, android-fragments, static

I have an app to receive data through bluetooth. The idea is that I have a bluetooth service running in the background, it is bound to the main activity. The service is created when a button is pressed on a fragment (I bind the service to the activity because I want to keep the bluetooth connection even fragment has been damaged.)

For this, When button in the fragment is pressed, I'm passing the handler from the fragment to the activity, the handler will then be passed to the service, so that I could update the fragment UI based on the received data.

However, I got `non-static method cannot be reference from a static context` for the `getBTService` method .I could not solve it as I cannot make the `bindService` static. Could anyone advice? Or is there a better way to manage this? Here is the relevant code:

**Main Activity:**

```
public void getBTService(Handler btHandler){
    this.mHandler = btHandler;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BluetoothService.class);
    bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (btService != null) {
        unbindService(connection);
        btBound = false;
    }
}

private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                   IBinder service) {
        BluetoothService.LocalBinder binder = (BluetoothService.LocalBinder) service;
        btService = binder.getService(mHandler);
        btBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        btBound = false;
    }
};
```

**Fragment:**

```
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signal, container, false);
    statusTV = root.findViewById(R.id.text_status);
    dataTV = root.findViewById(R.id.text_data);\
    openBtn = root.findViewById(R.id.openBtn);
    mChart = root.findViewById(R.id.chart);

    openBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                                   @Override
                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                      MainActivity.getBTService(mHandler);     
                                   }
                               }

    );
    return root;
}

private final Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
        switch ((msg.what)){
            case MainActivity.MessageConstants.MESSAGE_READ:
                String data = (String) msg.obj;
                updateTV("data", data);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You can use an interface callback to pass ur handler back to the activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this instead of call directly by `MainActivity`

```
    openBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                                   @Override
                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                     ((MainActivity) requireActivity()).getBTService(mHandler);     
                                   }
                               }
```